# Converting JSON object to javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to convert this json object:

```
"forms":
        {
            "Circle":
            {
                "color" : "red",
                "size" : "1"
            },
            "Square":
            {
                "color" : "blue",
                "size" : "3"
            },
            "triangle":
            {
                "color" : "black",
                "size" : "4"
            }
        }
```

Into an javascriptArray.
The array should contain formType, color and size.
I have created the following script

```
var formsArr=[]; 
$.each(forms, function(i, obj){ var form={color: obj.color, size: obj.size};
                formsArr.push(form);
```

The array only contains color and size. I want it to also containt formType ie. Circle, how can I get the key?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
var forms = {
  "Circle": {
    "color" : "red",
    "size" : "1"
  },
  "Square": {
    "color" : "blue",
    "size" : "3"
  },
  "triangle": {
    "color" : "black",
    "size" : "4"
  }
};

var result = Object.keys(forms).map(function(key) {
  return { type: key, color: this[key].color, size: this[key].size };
}, forms);
```

With jQuery:

```
var result = $.map(forms, function(val, key) {
  return { type: key, color: val.color, size: val.size };
});
```